# How can I get the last part of an url and build a redirect?

Tags: php

When I submit a post i get redirected to an url:

```
https://example.com/example/create/?usp_success=2&post_id=127065
```

Now I need to grab `127065` and build a redirect with it:

```
    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    // testing this but I don't how to get the last bit of the url
    // $newURL = "$actual_link/?p="
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

The final url where I'd like to redirect to would be:

```
https://example.com/example/create/?p=127065
```

**UPDATE**

If I do (as suggested in comment)

```
        $id = $_GET['post_id'];
        $newURL = get_home_url()."/".$id;
        header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

I get:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..
>   on line 42

And line 42 is:

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Comment: `$_GET['post_id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of two functions:  `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`

```
$actualLink = 'https://example.com/example/create/?usp_success=2&post_id=127065';
$queryArgs = [];
parse_str(parse_url($actualLink, PHP_URL_QUERY), $queryArgs);
if ($postID = $queryArgs['post_id']) {
    $newURL = sprintf("%s/?p=%s", $actual_link, $postID);
    header('Location: ' . $newURL);
}
```

`$queryArgs` will contain array:

```
Array
(
    [usp_success] => 2
    [post_id] => 127065
)
```

and you can get value of `post_id` using `$queryArgs['post_id']`

To fix this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by .. on line 42

You need to be sure that you don't have any outputs before calling `header()` function.

Answer (score 0):

use the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$url="https://example.com/example/create/?usp_success=2&post_id=127065";
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['post_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['post_id'];
    header('Location: https://example.com/example/create/?p='.$id);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.